# I cant export to .apk file my python program usin buildozer and Kivy

Tags: compiling, android, python3, debug, kivy

I was following this tutorial to learn how to export my project (wrote in python) to an .apk file. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pzsvN3fuBA0&t=4s) but I get this error while I was running Buildozer to debug the program.

```
# Command failed: ('/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--dist_name=kivy_example', '--bootstrap=sdl2', '--requirements=python3,kivy==2.0.0rc4,kivy_garden.graph,numpy', '--arch=arm64-v8a', '--arch=armeabi-v7a', '--copy-libs', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/home/kpa001/kivy_examples/graphs/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug')
# Error code: 1
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     LC_ADDRESS = 'es_BO.UTF-8'
#     LC_NAME = 'es_BO.UTF-8'
#     LC_MONETARY = 'es_BO.UTF-8'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/.mutter-Xwaylandauth.C99VC2'
#     LC_PAPER = 'es_BO.UTF-8'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu:GNOME'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     LC_IDENTIFICATION = 'es_BO.UTF-8'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     LC_TELEPHONE = 'es_BO.UTF-8'
#     LC_MEASUREMENT = 'es_BO.UTF-8'
#     LC_TIME = 'es_BO.UTF-8'
#     PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin'
#     LC_NUMERIC = 'es_BO.UTF-8'
#     MAIL = '/var/mail/root'
#     LOGNAME = 'root'
#     USER = 'root'
#     HOME = '/root'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     SUDO_COMMAND = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer android debug'
#     SUDO_USER = 'kpa001'
#     SUDO_UID = '1000'
#     SUDO_GID = '1000'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '30'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

please help me to resolve it, I'm new using linux-ubuntu and this is my first program to export.

Comment: Which command did you exactly use? Also, please consider opening an issue with the Github/Gitlab page of the parent project.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi thanks to answer; I used this command    `$ sudo buildozer android debug`

Comment: You can open an issue here https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues